# Accessing Javascript objects inside if conditionals, can that be done?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

This is my code from Free Code Camp Challenge "Profile Lookup", I am stuck with this code and my problem is the if conditions, how can get the test case to enter my first if condition?

```
var contacts = [
{
    "firstName": "Akira",
    "lastName": "Laine",
    "number": "0543236543",
    "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
},
{
    "firstName": "Harry",
    "lastName": "Potter",
    "number": "0994372684",
    "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
},
{
    "firstName": "Sherlock",
    "lastName": "Holmes",
    "number": "0487345643",
    "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
},
{
    "firstName": "Kristian",
    "lastName": "Vos",
    "number": "unknown",
    "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
}
];

function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){
// Only change code below this line
  for ( var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    if ( contacts[i].firstName === firstName && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      return contacts[i][prop];
    }
    else if (firstName !== contacts[i].firstName) {
      return "No such contact";
    }
    else if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop) === false) {
      return "No such property";
    }
  }
}

lookUpProfile("Harry", "likes");
```

What I am supposed to get is the value of "likes", which is ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"], and for that to happen, it should enter the first if condition, and there is the problem.

Comment: Please post your code as a code snippet instead of an image so we can adjust your code to help with your problem.

Comment: Please include code as text, now an image.

Comment: You should add your code as `code`, not a screenshot. This way people don't have to open another link to see what you are doing.

Comment: When the first name doesn't match on *any* iteration of the loop, you return an error.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Is there an error? Unexpected results? Can you post what you get and what you expect?

Comment: Your 3 if cases catch all possible scenarios, and all of them return. Your if will never execute more than one loop, and so will never see the second element ("Harry").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're returning early. No matter what, you're always returning the first iteration of the `contacts` collection if any of the conditions are met. What you need to do is store the answer in a local variable, outside of the loop, and return that value. Doing so assures that you've gone through all iterations without returning prematurely.

Try this:

```js
var contacts = [{
  "firstName": "Akira",
  "lastName": "Laine",
  "number": "0543236543",
  "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
}, {
  "firstName": "Harry",
  "lastName": "Potter",
  "number": "0994372684",
  "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
}, {
  "firstName": "Sherlock",
  "lastName": "Holmes",
  "number": "0487345643",
  "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
}, {
  "firstName": "Kristian",
  "lastName": "Vos",
  "number": "unknown",
  "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
}];

function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {
  var result = undefined;
  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    if (contacts[i].firstName === firstName) {
      result = contacts[i];
    } 
  }

  if (result === undefined) {
    return "No such contact";
  }
  if (result.hasOwnProperty(prop) === false) {
    return "No such property";
  }

  return result[prop];
}

console.log(lookUpProfile("Harry", "likes"));
```

A more functional and idiomatic way would be to use an array method such as [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: Actually, I tried this and it's a good point. Unfortunately, the variable "result" doesn't stop when I need it to stop, and the loop continues and overrides the answer that I wanted, the javascript object is larger than the one in the question, I posted an abridged version of it.

For example, when the result has the value of "likes", it continues and it meets another case that enters the same loop and the same if condition and overwrite "result" with new data that I don't need.

Comment: Care to update the question with a more robust dataset?

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

You are returning too early, so when the first result doesn't match "Harry", it automatically thinks the contact can't be found.

Seth's answer will work for your use case, but I'm thinking it will error out for other use cases if the contacts are in a different order in the array. The value of result will be overwritten later in the loop if there are more contacts to loop through after it finds the initial correct one.

I would rewrite lookUpProfile to something like this:

```
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {

  var profile = null;
  var err = null;

   for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
     if (firstName !== contacts[i].firstName) {
      err = "No such contact";
     } else if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop) === false) {
      err = "No such property";
     }
     if (contacts[i].firstName === firstName && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      profile =  contacts[i][prop];
     }
  }

  return (profile) ? profile : err;
}
```

You can check out the JSBin I created as well: http://jsbin.com/letesuhope/2/edit?js,console

Comment: although I am still a beginner, and I couldn't understand the changes, but it worked in more cases, there are two cases that still don't work:

    lookUpProfile("Bob", "number");
    lookUpProfile("Akira", "address");

can you explain what happened in this code?

Comment: Hi @AhmedSalahElDin I updated the code. It should work now to only return a single error message.

The first if/else statement checks for errors, and if there is an error, it stores it in the `err` variable.

The second if statement checks for a valid entry, and if so, saves it in the `profile` variable.

The last part is a shorthand for the if/else statement.  The longer way to write it would be:
`if (profile) { return profile } else { return err } `

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because "return" exits the for loop and stops after first item. Try with "console.log"

```
if ( contacts[i].firstName === firstName && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      console.log(i, contacts[i][prop]);
    }
    else if (firstName !== contacts[i].firstName) {
      console.log(i, 'No such contact');
    }
    else if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop) === false) {
      console.log(i, "No such property");
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ex3ntia/tj84gaox/

Comment: This doesn't help at all... the idea is to have the function return the matched user, not log the result for every iteration.

Comment: This example is to understand what happens. 
Usually to solve this problem using the "filter" function.

This may be your solution

https://jsfiddle.net/ex3ntia/tj84gaox/2/

Comment: That still doesn't help the OP. A more acceptable answer would be the fiddle you just linked. Of course filter would be a better option.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are returning a value in the first 'for' iteration.
You'll need to use a new variable, split the search in 2 steps and then return the result.

```
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){
  var contact;
  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    if (contacts[i].firstName === firstName) {
      contact = contacts[i];
    }
  }
  if (!contact) {
    return "No such contact";
  }
  if (contact.hasOwnProperty(prop) === false) {
    return "No such property";
  }
  return contact[prop];
}
```

Comment: I did that and the new variable got overwritten later .. because the loop continued.